# Where do I download sajdbc4.jar from?

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase, sqlanywhere

I do not have SQL Anywhere installed. I have tried jconn4, and jconn3, I have also tried, jodbc4, and none of them would do what I need.

I need a pure java, type 4, jdbc driver for Sybase, and as far as I can ascertain that's sajdbc.jar. But it is nowhere to be seen. I badly need this file. Is there anyone who can tell me where I can go to download this file ?

Comment: Have you tried searching on the SAP site, I think they own Sybase nowdays? http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01776.1600/doc/html/san1357754910584.html

Comment: @KevinHooke I have been to page, doesn't give a url to go to, does it?

Comment: The pure java (type 4) driver is jconnect (e.g. jconn4.jar). The sajdbc4.jar "4.0 SQL Anywhere JDBC driver" which implements the JDBC 4.0 standard is a type 1 driver relying on a native ODBC driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the [SQL Anywhere JDBC drivers](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbprogramming/pg-jdbc-4-0-load.html) documentation:

> The Java component of the SQL Anywhere JDBC 4.0 driver is included in the sajdbc4.jar file **installed into the Java subdirectory of your SQL Anywhere installation**. For Windows, the native component is dbjdbc12.dll in the bin32 or bin64 subdirectory of your SQL Anywhere installation; for Unix, the native component is libdbjdbc12.so. This component must be in the system path.

Comment: what is the relationship between the jar file and the native component?
I don't quite understand their explanation. 
Even though, I don't have SQL Anywhere and I am not the database administrator, and do not have access to all the directories.

Comment: @dariusiv The JDBC driver is partly implemented in non-Java code, so the "native" code must be available on the path, so the JVM can find it. This means that you need both the `.jar` file and the `.dll`/`.so` file for the JDBC driver to work. You need to ask the database administrator for the two files.

Comment: well, I am not sure, if the database admins have installed SQL Anywhere, I think, they just have a plain Sybase database. I simply wanted a JDBC driver that is pure java, and one that supports "LOAD TABLE" sql statements. jodbc4 does that, but it's not pure java, so I can't run it on unix. that's why I am desperately looking for sajdbc4.

Comment: Well, `sajdbc4.jar` is not *pure* Java either.

Comment: I have just installed SQL Anywhere 16 and the .jar file that should be in the BIN32 or BIN64 folder is not there. Any ideas where this would be?

Comment: @MichaelCropper Read answer again: The **.jar** file is in the `java` folder, not a `binXX` folder. The `binXX` folder has the **.dll** files.

Comment: There is no /java/ folder on the 16 version. I downloaded the 12 version which included the /java/ folder on the install. Not sure why this has changed in the latest version.

Comment: @MichaelCropper Well, both [SQL Anywhere 16.0](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbprogramming/pg-jdbc-4-0-load.html) and [SQL Anywhere 17](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sqla170/en/html/3bd896036c5f101489c4ea2fec763545.html) documentation says the `sajdbc4.jar` file is in the `java` folder, and that the `dbjdbcXX.dll` file is in the `binXX` folder, so maybe you neglected to select the Java component during install. Maybe you need to do a custom installation and check off Java/JDBC to get it installed.

Comment: I've downloaded [this package](http://d5d4ifzqzkhwt.cloudfront.net/sqla16client/SQLA16_Windows_Client.exe) from SAP website and I found the _sajdbc4.jar_ file under `Program Files\SQL Anywhere 16\Java` folder.

Answer (score 5):

i met the same issue these days, and i just fix this :)

First, visit this site and register : https://www.sap.com/cmp/syb/crm-xu15-int-asewindm/index.html

than u can download "ASE_Suite.winx64.zip"

open this zip file and you can see the view like this:
[image]

and than click "setupConsole.exe", you can see:
[image]

select custom , and you may select jconnect4, like this:
[image]

At the end, you can find jconnect at the place 
[image]

hope this would help:))

Comment: Thank you.  This was the only link online i found that provided me instructions to get through the registration process to download the jConnect jdbc driver.

Comment: it's glad to know what i did is helpful :) thank u:))